# dialogue control is not modal

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

This [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/U8gy1a?p=preview) captures behavior of events in Kendo dialog launched from the service.  I need to be able to apply business logic to the result (user input) and decide if the event should be cancelled but the 'outside' code always runs before the 'inside' code.  The dialog is not modal as the documentation would suggest.

```
  public showConfirmation() {
  const dialog: DialogRef = this.dialogService.open({
      title: "Please confirm",
      content: "Are you sure?",
      actions: [
          { text: "No" },
          { text: "Yes", primary: true }
      ],
      width: 450,
      height: 200,
      minWidth: 250
  }).result.subscribe((result) => {
      if (result instanceof DialogCloseResult) {
          console.log("close");
      } else {
          console.log("action", result);
          //setTimeout(2000);
          let date = Date.now()
          console.log('inside', date);
      }

      this.result = JSON.stringify(result);
  });

  let date = Date.now()
  console.log('outside' + date);
```

}

Comment: describe your issue again.